Why do I get this error for configuring my model in EF Core?
I'm trying to configure my EF Core. I want to DRY and reuse code. Therefore I created a simple method to filter out all of the properties of all entity types in my model:
public List<IMutableProperty> GetProperties(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Func<IProperty, bool> filter)
{
    var properties = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .ToList()
        .Where(filter) // This line causes that error
        .ToList();
    return properties;
}

But I get this error:

error CS0311: The type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRow' in the generic type or method 'TypedTableBaseExtensions.Where(TypedTableBase, Func<TRow, bool>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Here's how I intend to use it:
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ConfigureTenants(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureLocales(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureKeys(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureGuids(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureSlugs(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureOrders(modelBuilder);
        ConfigRelatedItems(modelBuilder);
    }

    public void ConfigureTenants(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var properties = GetProperties(modelBuilder, p => p.ClrType == typeof(string) && p.Name == "Tenant");
        properties.ForEach(p => p.SetDefaultValue("'main'"));
    }

    public void ConfigureLocales(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var properties = GetProperties(modelBuilder, p => p.ClrType == typeof(string) && p.Name == "Locale");
        properties.ForEach(p => p.SetDefaultValue("'en'"));
    }

Why do I get that error? What does this code has to do with TRow at all?

IMutableProperty is not IProperty. Add more simplier solution.

I suggest redesigning the approach and exposing PropertyBuilder<T>.
Applying a default action is straightforward using builders:
public void ConfigureTenants(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyToProperties<string>(p => p.Name == "Tenant", p => p.HasDefaultValueSql("main"));
}

public void ConfigureLocales(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyToProperties<string>(p => p.Name == "Locale", p => p.HasDefaultValueSql("en"));
}

And the implementation:
#pragma warning disable EF1001

public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder ApplyToProperties<TPropertyType>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Func<IMutableProperty, bool> filter, Action<PropertyBuilder<TPropertyType>> action)
    {
        var properties = modelBuilder.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties().Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(TPropertyType)))
            .Where(filter)
            .Select(p => new PropertyBuilder<TPropertyType>(p))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            action(property);
        }
        return modelBuilder;
    }
}

